# Vector operations from nonlinear continnum mechanics with large deformation for curl of a vector $p_i$=$\epsilon_{ijk} s_{k,l}u_{l,j}$

Tags: classical-mechanics, vectors, continuum-mechanics, non-linear-systems

I just found there is an expression from the curl operation of a vector component $p_i=\epsilon_{ijk}s_{k,l}u_{l,j}$, where $\mathbf {u}$ is deformation and $\mathbf {s}$ is another variable dependent on $\bf u$.  These equations are not presented in books, but it is needed when I try to implement the full equations for multiple physics fields with large variables which will result in a set of nonlinear equations.  This expression might appear in some other books and applications but I did not find some references.  I need to find the result in vector operations such as the vector $\bf {p}$ is the combination of curls and divs of vectors such as
$$\bf p = p\left(\nabla \times \bf u, \nabla\times s, \nabla\cdot u, \nabla\cdot s, \cdots\right)$$.
Since the physical quantities such as electric field, magnetic field, and mechanical field are given in vectors from the beginning.

Looks like there is no simple expression.  My initial result is a lengthy combination
$$\bf p = \nabla\times \bf s\times\nabla\times\bf u+\nabla\cdot\bf u\nabla\times \bf s+\nabla\cdot\bf s\nabla\times \bf u-\nabla\times\bf s\cdot\bf u\nabla-\nabla\times\bf u\cdot\bf s\nabla$$
It is much more complicated than I hoped.  I am looking for simpler expressions.

With the help of this site and other sources, the expression is simplified to

$$\bf p={\it \epsilon_{ijk} s_{k,l} u_{l,j}}=\nabla\times\left(\bf u\cdot \bf s\nabla\right)-\bf u\cdot\left(\nabla\times\bf s\nabla\right)$$
with usual definitions of tensors.
The expression cannot be given by combinations of products of curl and div without using the tensors.
This is the simplest form I can obtain so far.

Comment: Why is the compact index expression not sufficient? Why do you need anything else?

Comment: How can your initial result have terms that end with a $\nabla$ and are thus operators?

Comment: The tensor $\partial_i s_j$ for a vector $\mathbf{s}$ has a piece that can't be expressed just in terms of the curl or the divergence of $\mathbf{s}$.  Roughly speaking, the divergence is the trace of this tensor and the curl is its antisymmetric part, but that still leaves its symmetric trace-free part (which is still inherently a tensor).  So it's plausible that this quantity can't be expressed just in terms of curls and divergences.

Comment: You are definitely right on this.  The expression we can get is that it is a combination of tensor, curls, and divs.

Comment: What s the meaning of $p$ and $u$? I know it s probably irrelevant to answer the question but just for the seek of curiosity.

Comment: The variables are from the couplings of physical fields in the large deformation electromagnetic solids.  Vector $\bf u$ is the deformation, then $\bf p$ can be electric and magnetic fields.  It is part of the coupled nonlinear differential equation set.

Comment: I'm still not familiar with the notation that you're using. Can you clarify what $\mathbf{s}\nabla$ and $\mathbf{u}\nabla$ are?

Comment: It is the standard notation in Elasticity and Continnum Mechanics.  For a vector $\bf v$, $$\bf v\nabla=\left(\nabla\bf v\right)^T$$

Answer (score 0):

$∇×(·∇) - (∇×[)·∇] = ·∇∇^†×$, where $∇^†$ applies to the left.